# Unity 5 skybox reflection on terrain

Tags: unity, terrain, terrain-rendering

I begin to use Unity 5. I added a terrain and a skybox in my game but there is always reflection of sky on my terrain. As you see in the picture.
 I added texture to solve the problem. But the reflection of skybox is always there.
Why terrain is too shiny and like mirror in Unity 5?
Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why terrain is too shiny is because  of default terrain material.
By default terrain material is `Built in Standart` and this material is too shiny and smooth.When we change this option to other option. It resolve the problem.
In my case i change to `Built in Legacy Diffuse` it solved my problem.

[image]